# Multi-controller with annotations in Spring 3.1.1

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, springsource

i am trying multi controller in Springs 3.1.1 framework using annotation. but its not working i tried enabling support for annotation by configuring xml file in different ways. here is my code

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.web" />

<bean id="userKey" class="controllers.UserController" />
<bean id="newUserKey" class="controllers.UserFormController" />
<bean id="demoKey" class="controllers.demoController" />


<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            <prop key="user.htm">userKey</prop>
            <prop key="add_user.htm">newUserKey</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class multi extends MultiActionController {

@RequestMapping("/multi/add")
public ModelAndView add(){
    return new ModelAndView("demo", "message", "Add method called");
}

@RequestMapping("/user/divide.htm")
public ModelAndView divide(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return new ModelAndView("demo", "message", "divide method called");
}
}
```

web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I tried this:

Solutions 1:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Solution 2:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you are mixing 2 strategies you have a `Controller` which is annotated with `@Controller` now which one should take precedence? Fix your controller by **not** extending `MultiActionController` as this is intended to not work with annotations.

```
@Controller
public class multi {

    @RequestMapping("/multi/add")
    public ModelAndView add(){
        return new ModelAndView("demo", "message", "Add method called");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user/divide.htm")
    public ModelAndView divide(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return new ModelAndView("demo", "message", "divide method called");
    }
}
```

Your solution 2 is using the older Spring 2.5 based `@RequestMapping` way of things, you should use the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` which both are registered when you use `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

Basically what you need in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

   <!-- Scan only for @Controllers -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller />
    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!-- The index controller. -->
    <mvc:view-controller view-name="index" />

</beans>
```

This will register everything that is need to process the `@Controller` annotation (the `<context:component-scan ... />` and the `@RequestMapping` annotations (the `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. You don't need the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` as that is to be used with `Controller` and not with `@Controller` at least as of Spring 3.x.

Comment: Thanks M. Denium. I tried your solution but its giving exception The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.  I checked schema location at top but i could not figure out what is the reson for this exception. i tried spring-mvc.xsd and spring-mvc-3.1.xsd. Please suggest solution.

Comment: Do you have all the necessary (spring-webmvc) and correct jars (no conflicting versions!). It is recommended to use the version-less xsd files as those will point to the most recent versions of the xsd. There might be a typo somewhere as I typed this online and not in an editor.

Comment: Yes, there is typing mistake but i fixed that. I have created new project with NetBeans IDE so all the Jar file are present. do we need any jar file in order to support <mvc:annotation-driven/>.

Comment: Not sure why all the jar files would be present because you use netbeans. I strongly suggest using maven or Gralde to manage your dependencies. You shouldn't rely on your ide to do that for you IMHO.

Comment: You were right. I missed space at one place in schema location. thanks @M. Deinum